# Is sterilization of dogs and cats ok?

Tags: animals

I know that sterilization of people is not ok according to Quran. But what about animals, like dogs and cats. Is it ok to sterilize them so they cannot have their children born?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bismillahir Rahmanir Raheem*

As salaam Alaykum,

I am with Imam Ahmad when he said,

> I do not like for a man to neuter anything, rather that is makrooh
>   because of the prohibition on causing pain to animals.

---

The following is from [islam Q&A](http://www.islam-qa.com/en/ref/10502):

> Preventing your cat from reproducing is preventing a natural process
>   that Allaah has created in it. Undoubtedly the rulings on animals are
>   not as serious as in the case of humans, but this does not mean
>   violating the rights of the creation of Allaah.
>
> If this operation will cause harm, or it will cause complications for
>   the cat, then it is not permissible. The prohibition against causing
>   harm is general and includes harm against both humans and animals.
>   There follow some of the ahaadeeth that indicate this:
>
> > It was narrated from Ibn ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) that
> >     the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “A woman
> >     entered Hell because of a cat which she tied up and did not feed, nor
> >     did she allow it to eat of the vermin of the earth.”
>
> The vermin of the earth means mice, etc.
>
> (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 3140; Muslim, 2242. There is also a similar
>   report from Abu Hurayrah).
>
> > It was narrated from Jaabir ibn ‘Abd-Allaah that a donkey whose face
> >     had been branded passed by the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah
> >     be upon him), and he said, “May Allaah curse the one who branded him.”
>
> (Narrated by Muslim, 2217).
>
> ---
>
> Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:
>
> If there are too many cats and they are a nuisance, and if the
>   operation will not harm them, then there is nothing wrong with it,
>   because this is better than killing them after they have been created.
>   But if the cats are ordinary cats and are not causing a nuisance,
>   perhaps it is better to leave them alone to reproduce.
>
> Fataawa Islamiyyah, 4/448